80s/90s Sci-Fi TV show about an alien with a small flying friend
I saw a live action TV show when I was a kid and I can not remember the title and I only have vague memories of it.
It was running at the end of the 80s, beginning of 90s. 
It is a science-fiction show about a guy who came from a foreign planet and he has a small shell-like friend with a large eye always following him flying around and talking. There are also slimy stuff, some kind of alien enemy.
Any idea?

Live-action or animated?

@Hegemon live action, I added to the question.

Sounds like  Hard Time on Planet Earth, a short-lived sci-fi show from 1989.

Jesse, an alien is sent to Earth and finds himself in Los Angeles. His only companion is a floating, orb-shaped parole officer named Control. Doomed to stay on Earth until he can show compassion, Control helps him lead as normal a life as possible, but not knowing Earthly ways he often finds himself in trouble.

His sidekick Control was basically a big floating eye in a conch shell. Here's the intro:




Yess! This is the movie I was looking for. You made my day. Now I just have to find it online to watch...
